Does the convergence of $\Sigma a_n$, along with the fact that $a_n \geq 0$, always imply the convergence of $\Sigma \sqrt{a_n}$?
My thought process is as follows:
Assume that $a_n \geq 0$ and that $\Sigma a_n$ converges.  Since $\Sigma a_n$ converges, then  $a_n \rightarrow 0$.  Thus, for some $\beta$ and $N$, $0 \leq a_n < \beta < 1$ when $n \geq N$.  Therefore, $$0 \leq \sqrt[n]{\sqrt{a_n}} < \sqrt[n]{\sqrt{ \beta}} < 1.$$
Letting $\alpha = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup \sqrt[n]{\sqrt{a_n}}$, it follows that $\alpha < 1$.  By the Root Test, $\Sigma \sqrt{a_n}$ therefore converges.
Is this proof coherent or am I misunderstanding something?
Edit: user lhf has found a counter example.

Try $a_n=1/n^2$

Remember:  the harmonic series is almost always a counterexample to whatever you're thinking.

Your error is that you can’t be sure that $\alpha<1$

Your argument fails because strict inequalities are not preserved under limits. If $\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{a_n}} < 1$ for all $n$, all we can conclude is that $\limsup_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{a_n}} \leq 1$. Note the $\leq$, which means the Root Test fails.
As noted in a comment, let $a_n = \frac{1}{n^p}$ for any $1 < p < 2$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{a_n}$ diverges by the standard results for $p$-series.

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ converges and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ diverges, the statement is false. Therefore, your proof is wrong. Your mistake lies in assuming that just because you always have $\sqrt[n]{\sqrt\beta}<1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\sqrt\beta}<1$.
